# Re-firing Jquery script after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a short Jquery script to hide a div-element upon page load, which reappears under certain conditions. When a user scrolls down the page, new content will load with Ajax, containing that very same div-element that I want to hide. How can I fire that Jquery again upon said div-element being loaded?

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
           $(window).load(function() {
            $( ".the_button" ).hide();
            if (...certain condition is met...) { 
                $( ".the_button" ).show();
            }
           });
    })(jQuery);
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="the_button"><button>Share</button></div>

<p>Ajax-loaded button:</p>

<div class="the_button"><button>Share</button></div>

</body>
```

The button shows on subsequent Ajax loads, but I want it to be hidden like the first one.

Comment: Do you have access to function that loads new elements or using some external library for that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery to hide it on page load in the first place? It might be better to just have the default CSS for `.the_button` set to `display:none`, so as soon as a button loads it's automatically hidden and never displayed until you show it with jQuery.

Comment: Why not give it display: none css property to begin with. no need the initial hide with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both scripts inside "filename.js" - file and include it in your html with script tag.

Then just put your whole script inside function like this

```
$(window).load(function () {
    function functionName(){
    $(".the_button").hide()
    if (...certain condition is met...) {
      $(".the_button").show()
    }
    functionName()
      (...calling it right after load...)
    $.ajax({
        (...ajax things goes here...)
      })
      .done(function(){
        functionName()
          (...call your function again here...)
      })
    }
  })
```

This thing could help you handle ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/